# Making a stack frame with push/lea offset/sub instead of push/mov/sub?

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I'm analysing a c++ function compiled with vc++ (probably vs10) and I never saw this prologue pattern before.

It seems to be a **stdcall** but the prologue is a little bit different:

**stdcall** usually starts the function with the following prologue pattern:

```
push   ebp
mov    ebp, esp
sub    esp, const
```

However the prologue of this function I'm analysing is the following:

```
push   ebp
lea    ebp, [esp - 0x4C]
sub    esp, 0x80
```

Analysing other functions in the same PE that uses the same prologue/epilogue it seems the **RETN** always come after a **LEAVE** instruction, just another thing I never saw in a regular **cdecl** function.

I'm wondering about why the compiler did that. It appears to open space on **ESP** (by `sub esp, const`), so why it opens another block of stack by `lea ebp, [esp - const]`?

Does anyone know why the compiler does that? Is that a different call convention from **stdcall**?

I did some research on the net as well as studied this specific assembly code to find out but didn't discover the need of that.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT with screens of the prologue/epilogue:

**Prologue**
[image]

**Epilogue**
[image]

**A call to the function**
[image]

Comment: That `lea` doesn't reserve anything, it just offsets the frame pointer. You can use this to be able to address more of the stack frame with an `sbyte` offset.

Comment: Both methods actually allocate the same amount of space on the stack (equal to **const**). The difference is that in the first case _EBP_ contains the value of _ESP_ before the allocation of **const** bytes. In the second _EBP_ contains the value of _ESP_ after the stack allocation of **stack** bytes. I think you may have to show us the entire function to see how this is being used.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I edited the topic with print screens of the dissasembly of the following: prologue and epilogue of the function, and a call to the function.

Comment: The `ret` with an argument is used because the calling convention is `stdcall`

Comment: Yeah, found out that in further analysis @harold. Any tips on the strange prologue/epilogue? Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking regarding `leave`. The frame pointer offsetting is just a trick for code density, avoiding having to code 32bit displacements.

Comment: On top of what harold said (about offsetting the frame pointer for code density), I was curious in the screenshot if there was more to the epilogue code. You'll see that three things are done in the epilogue. **const** is added back to EBP, `leave` and then `ret`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers @harold and Michael. So that difference between the "usual" prologue/epilogue pattern is just a compiler optimization? Could you guys give some text references so I can dig deeper in this case?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: you don't need to modify EBP (by adding `const`) before restoring the caller's EBP with `leave`.

Comment: @PeterCordes : You do in this case where the prologue offset _EBP_ by a constant. You have to make up for the difference in the epilogue caused by using `lea ebp, [esp - const]` to set _EBP_ initially.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: oh right, I forgot about the `mov esp, ebp` part of `leave`, which often isn't necessary (and in this case actually detrimental if you can point esp to the right place to pop).  I was just thinking of the `pop` part.

Comment: The entire idea here of course as Harold is trying to say is that if you offset _EBP_ in the prologue and can get most stack accesses to fit withing a signed byte (+127 to -128) then the instructions accessesing stack variables can be shortened by using 1 byte displacement rather than 4 byte displacement.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm asking this because i couldn't realize what was the exactly call convention used in that function, never saw that. Its just for knowledge purpose.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelPetch, I guess I fully understand what harold said now :D

Comment: EDIT: nvm, i got it!

Comment: @MichaelPetch if you answer the topic 'll accept. If no one answer it i'll write my own using what you guys explained.

Comment: I'll leave it to someone else. I am pretty sure I have seen this discussed before in another SO answer, but I can't seem to find it at the moment.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Okay then.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I wrote an answer, if you could check if I missed something that will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As no one in the comments wrote an answer here we go...

The reason of that difference in the prologue/epilogue between the "usual" **stdcall** and the one I talk in the topic is compiler optmization for code density.

Offsetting `EBP` in the prologue the compiler is able to shorten the instructions in the function that accesses some stack variables. It can now access a larger chunk of stack memory (depending on how long the prologue offset `EBP`) with a single byte displacement - using `EBP + N` and `EBP - M` to access local variables (where `N` and `M` are a const between -128 and + 127). Of course instructions that access variables beyond that EBP's offset will use 4 bytes displacement, but the overall code of that function will be shorter using this optimization trick.